# how to turn name into email address in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that I want to send individual sections of (including the header) to certain people. I have a field titled "Name" that I would like the macro to pull the name and fill in with the same domain. so if there was a name "Jack Smith" I would want to send the section of the spreadsheet to "Jack.Smith@xyzcompany.com"

Below is what my spreadsheet columns are. I want to be able to highlight a select number of rows and email them to the corresponding name by changing the 'Name' column to an email address format of 'Firstname.Lastname@xyzcompany.com'

Columns:
Date Added
Code
Name
Location

The below is what I have so far.

```
Sub rr()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Selection

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With r.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
.To = "Firstname.Lastname@xyzcompany.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "List Info"
.attachements.Add ""
.Send
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to Range.Find "Jack Smith"? If you already know what you are looking for, there is no point in looking; just use what you have and replace spaces with periods.

Comment: How would that work for the .To field in the code? I'm asking how to use the 'Name' column in the .To field of the code. so Jack Smith will be converted to the email form for each different selection of my spreadsheet. Let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Keep going. Be very specific. Don't post in Comments; [edit] your question to include this new information.

Comment: Where is this field? Is it a cell? A userform?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 they are cells. the column is titled 'Name' with a handful of names in it.

Comment: you've added a rogue *e* in attachements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to use Selection as the governing body to determine the recipients, simply loop through each cell in the Selection and modify it on the fly.

```
Option Explicit
Public Const dom As String = "@xyzcompany.com"    

Sub rr()

    Dim r As Range, eml As String

    For Each r In Selection

        r.Parent.EnvelopeVisible = True

        'replace space with period; append domain
        eml = Replace(r.Text, Chr(32), Chr(46)) & dom

        With r.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
            .To = eml
            .CC = vbNullString
            .BCC = vbNullString
            .Subject = "List Info"
            .attachments.Add vbNullString
            .send
        End With

    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: might be a dumb question, i'm new at this if you can't tell haha. what does Chr(32), Chr(46) mean?

Comment: please see [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). For all intents and purposes, they are a space (e.g. `\ `) and a period (e.g. `.`) which is why I left the comment in the code.

Comment: gave me a runtime error 438. when I hit debut it showed ' r.Parent.EnvelopeVisible = True' highlighted

Comment: My bad. I misread `ActiveWorkBOOK.EnvelopeVisible = True` to be `ActiveWorkSHEET.EnvelopeVisible = True`. Change it back to the original or use `r.Parent.Parent.EnvelopeVisible = True`

Comment: okay that worked, but it's not reading the name from the name column, its just reading the first cell. How do I define it to read the name from the right column?